# Recieving SyntaxError in Unit Testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, syntax-error

I have updated this post; please see the edits following the bolded text.

I'm learning javascript and am practicing unit tests. The latest test I've completed keeps returning a Syntax Error though I've (1) verified the accuracy of the expected results by copying and pasting the module's working output into the unit test and (2) confirmed that each bracket, parenthesis and curly bracket is paired up appropriately. I've tried checking for invisible characters in ATOM text editor based on an answer given in another StackOverflow question and didn't immediately see any.

The error message:

```
SyntaxError: C:/Users/elber/.atom/packages/script/node_modules/.bin/babel: Unexpected token, expected , (2380:16)
  2378 |     assert.strictEqual(result.commands,
  2379 |       [
> 2380 |         Command { commandType: 'MODE_CHANGE', value: 'LOW_POWER' },
       |                 ^
  2381 |         Command { commandType: 'STATUS_CHECK', value: undefined }
  2382 |       ]
```

The correct output which was copied and pasted into the unit test:

```
[
  Command { commandType: 'MODE_CHANGE', value: 'LOW_POWER' },
  Command { commandType: 'STATUS_CHECK', value: undefined }
]
```

The modules and related unit test:

```
// ---------------- Command module ---------------

class Command {
  constructor(commandType, value) {
    this.commandType = commandType;
    if (!commandType) {
      throw Error("Command type required.");
    }
    this.value = value;
  }

}

// ---------------- Message module ---------------

class Message {
  constructor(name, commands) {
    this.name = name;
    if (!name) {
      throw Error("Name required.");
    }
    this.commands = commands;
  }

}

// ---------------- running modules for correct output ---------------

let commands = [new Command('MODE_CHANGE', 'LOW_POWER'), new Command('STATUS_CHECK')];
let message = new Message('Test message with two commands', commands);

console.log (message.commands);

// ---------------- Unit Test ---------------

describe("Message class", function() {

  it("contains a commands array passed into the constructor as 2nd argument", function() {
    let result = new Message ("Test message with two commands", [new Command('MODE_CHANGE', 'LOW_POWER'), new Command('STATUS_CHECK')]);

    assert.strictEqual(result.commands,
      [
        Command { commandType: 'MODE_CHANGE', value: 'LOW_POWER' },
        Command { commandType: 'STATUS_CHECK', value: undefined }
      ]
  );
  });
});
```

**I also tried updating the code *without* using the class name (so copied and pasted the following code suggested in the answers into the unit test description, below):**

```
describe("Message class", function() {

  it("contains a commands array passed into the constructor as 2nd argument", function() {
    let result = new Message ("Test message with two commands", [new Command('MODE_CHANGE', 'LOW_POWER'), new Command('STATUS_CHECK')]);

    assert.strictEqual(result.commands,
      [
        { commandType: 'MODE_CHANGE', value: 'LOW_POWER' },
        { commandType: 'STATUS_CHECK', value: undefined }
      ]
  );
  });
});
```

In Repl.it : with that edit, the resulting error message in Repl.it looks like this:

```
Failures:
1) Message class contains a commands array passed into the constructor as 2nd argument
  Message:
    AssertionError: Expected "actual" to be reference-equal to "expected":
    + actual - expected
    
      [
    +   Command {
    -   {
          commandType: 'MODE_CHANGE',
          value: 'LOW_POWER'
        },
    +   Command {
    -   {
          commandType: 'STATUS_CHECK',
          value: undefined
        }
      ]
  Stack:
    error properties: Object({ generatedMessage: true, code: 'ERR_ASSERTION', actual: [ Command({ commandType: 'MODE_CHANGE', value: 'LOW_POWER' }), Command({ commandType: 'STATUS_CHECK', value: undefined }) ], expected: [ Object({ commandType: 'MODE_CHANGE', value: 'LOW_POWER' }), Object({ commandType: 'STATUS_CHECK', value: undefined }) ], operator: 'strictEqual' })
        at <Jasmine>
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (/home/runner/mars-rover-starter-1/spec/message.spec.js:34:12)
        at <Jasmine>
        at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
        at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:137:15)
```

In ATOM, the resulting error message in ATOM looks like this:

```
[stdin]:2377
describe("Message class", function () {
^

ReferenceError: describe is not defined
    at [stdin]:2377:1
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:120:20)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:311:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([stdin]-wrapper:10:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at evalScript (internal/process/execution.js:94:25)
    at internal/main/eval_stdin.js:29:5
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/process/execution.js:207:5)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1221:12)
[Finished in 0.631s]
```

In the above example, the ATOM error could be due to my not having imported the Jasmine module? And maybe the Repl.it error is just a Repl.it issue. Just thought I'd check back in to see if there was any additional insight given the new info.

Answer (score 1):

The output copied should be as follows

```
[
  { commandType: 'MODE_CHANGE', value: 'LOW_POWER' },
  { commandType: 'STATUS_CHECK', value: undefined }
]
```

> The prefix `Command` is just the name of the object which is displayed
> as part of better logging. The syntax does not consist of this.

Comment: thanks for responding. I should have mentioned in my post that I'd tried removing the class name "Command" before without success; but I went ahead and copied and pasted the code you'd shared just in case there was something I'd missed and still received an error. Did the code work on your end? I'll update my original message with the outcome of that attempt on my end (both in Repl.it and in Atom).

Comment: now its a describe not defined error. have you installed the proper testing framework module ?

Comment: I did in Repl.it (which is where we've primarily been learning so far, though we are transitioning into Visual Studio shortly). On Repl.it all of my other tests are passing. I noted the updated Repl.it error message in the edited question above.

Comment: You have to run your tests using your testing framework command, not node. eg mocha

Comment: Hi, thanks. I'm mainly running the tests using the Repl.it software, and am using Jasmine module for testing. All my other tests work (I have a total of 14 tests for this exercise). This is the only test that's giving me an error in Repl.it, still.